# Semantics of .WRITE(NULL, NULL, NULL) when updating a VARBINARY(max) column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, varbinary, varbinarymax

What are the semantics of the following query

```
UPDATE table
SET column .WRITE(NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

if `column` is of `VARBINARY(max)` type and its contents are not `NULL`?

A quick test suggests that the query
is a no-op:

```
--DROP TABLE [table]
CREATE TABLE [table] ([column] VARBINARY(max))
INSERT INTO [table] VALUES (0x12345678)
UPDATE [table]
SET [column] .WRITE(NULL, NULL, NULL)
SELECT * FROM [table]
```

Executing it does not alter the data in the `column`. However, I can't seem to find evidence in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Have I overlooked something, or is this no-op behavior likely to change?

Comment: What does "a no-op" mean for you? Your syntax is incorrect, as the documentation you linked to shows (see the examples under "Updating Large Object Data Types"). This works for me: `update dbo.Mytable set MyColumn.Write(null, null, null)`

Comment: @Pondlife: Thanks, edited. It works for me too, but is this behavior documented?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking: what is "this behavior"? The parameters are documented, and the remarks say that you cannot set a value to NULL or update a NULL column value using `write`. It sounds like you're seeing something that you don't expect or understand, but since you haven't shown any query results or output I'm not sure what anyone can tell you. If you post a complete working example that shows exactly the behaviour that you're asking about, someone may be able to clarify it.

Comment: @krlmlr: Actually the doc that you linked to logically implies that `.WRITE(NULL,NULL,NULL)` will try to truncate the column to the length that it already is.  I.E., effectively a no-op.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: Care to elaborate on this in an answer? I'll be glad to award a bounty for a logical explanation :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually a careful reading of the doc that was linked to ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)) logically implies that `.WRITE(NULL,NULL,NULL)` should try to truncate the column to the length that it already is. I.E., effectively a no-op.

Note the italicized sections in this extract from the Doc:

> **`.WRITE (expression,@Offset,@Length)`:**
>
> Specifies that a section of the
>   value of column_name is to be modified. expression replaces @Length
>   units starting from @Offset of column_name. ...
>
> **`expression`:** is the value that is copied to
>   column_name. ... *If expression is set to NULL, @Length is
>   ignored, and the value in column_name is truncated at the specified
>   @Offset*.
>
> **`@Offset`:** is the starting point in the value of column_name at
>   which expression is written. ... *If @Offset is NULL, the
>   update operation appends expression at the end of the existing
>   column_name value and @Length is ignored*. ...

So if `@Offset` is NULL, then it is treated as though it were the current length of the column.

And, if `expression` is NULL, the column is truncated at the `@Offset` value.

Ergo, if both are NULL, then the column is truncated at its current length.  Which I take to mean that it effectively does nothing.

Comment: So, `@Length` is ignored because `expression` is `NULL`, *and* because `@Offset` is `NULL`. So indeed the observed behavior is the only logical explanation. I'm just wondering why this isn't stated explicitly... Thanks for the careful analysis!